# Sending signal from kernel to user space

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

How to get signal from kernel space to user space?

Answer (score 6):

To get the signal from kernel to user space use the following code in your user space and kernel space code as below :

user space application :

```
signal(SIGIO, &signal_handler_func); 
fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
oflags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, oflags | FASYNC);
```

define **signal_handler_func** function :

```
void signal_handler_func (int sig)
{

//handle the action corresponding to the signal here
}
```

kernel Space Module :

```
int ret = 0;
struct siginfo info;
memset(&info, 0, sizeof(struct siginfo));
info.si_signo = SIG_TEST;
info.si_code = SI_QUEUE;
info.si_int = 1234;  

send_sig_info(SIG_TEST, &info, t);//send signal to user land
```

t is the PID of the user application.

Comment: Can you please provide the complete example?

Comment: Also, how will I know the pid of the user application?

Comment: user space application can register with the module at the time of initialisation using netlink sockets and , in register message they can specify their PID.

Comment: @dexterous_stranger I did this but using `kill_proc_info()` instead of `send_sig_info()`. You can use the `for_each_process()` macro to find the process by name and get it's PID.

Answer (score 1):

Use the kernel API function kill_proc_info(int sig, struct siginfo *info, pid_t pid)

**NOTE** This is actually a bad answer. The functions does send a signal to user space but the right way to do this, as the asker intended is to use the fasync character device method as documented here: http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch05.html#t4

Comment: #include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/signal.h>
int init_module()
{
//       int i,res=0;
 //     char msg1[80];
        struct siginfo info;
        printk(KERN_ALERT"\n HELLO WORLD!!");
        info.si_signo = 14; // GIVE YOU SIGNAL NUMBER HERE!!!!!
        info.si_errno = 0;
        info.si_code = SI_USER;
        info.si_pid = current->tgid;
        info.si_uid = current->uid;
 kill_proc_info(14, &info, 553); 
        return 0;
}void cleanup_module(){printk(KERN_ALERT"\n Good bye world!!");}MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

Comment: sir tell me what is the header file?

Comment: header file for kernel API function kill_proc_info(int sig, struct siginfo *info, pid_t pid)

Comment: while executing my program I got following error

Comment: /home/wasimtabrez/Work/int/signal2.c: In function ‘init_module’:
/home/wasimtabrez/Work/int/signal2.c:24: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home/wasimtabrez/Work/int/signal2.c:25: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home/wasimtabrez/Work/int/signal2.c:27: error: implicit declaration of function ‘kill_proc_info’
make[2]: *** [/home/wasimtabrez/Work/int/signal2.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/wasimtabrez/Work/int] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-28-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: This may help http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/multi/kernel_user_space_howto-6.html

Answer (score 1):

There is something called a NetLink interface which provides a set of API's for communication between a kernel process and a user process.It is similar to the socket interface and the communication is asynchronous and hence is preferred to IOCTL.

Overview here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356