# Is sending real-time signal from kernel with SI_QUEUE is required for sending `struct siginfo.si_int`?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, signals, linux-device-driver

## Short question

According to [`signal(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

> 2. If  the  signal  is  sent  using `sigqueue(2)`, an accompanying value
>    (either an integer or a pointer) can be sent with the  signal.

The struct siginfo has a field `si_int` for carrying data.

```c
typedef struct siginfo {
    int si_signo;
    int si_errno;
    int si_code;
    int si_int; //  This is actually a macro specifying a union value in struct siginfo
```

Does manpage description above apply when sending signal from *kernel module* by using `send_sig_info()`? Or is it just applied when a prgram calling system call `sigqueue()` in userspace?
I've track down from kernel's `send_sig_info()` but not found anything related to `SI_QUEUE`. Tried to look into glibc but I don't know how to read [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.31/C/ident/sigqueue)..

Update at 2020/11/24:

[Glärbo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64923000/4123703)make sense.

Since kernel code serves for userspace, the data carried by `siginfo` should serve userspace program. Where `si_code == SI_QUEUE` should be the sign of checking `siginfo`'s `si_int`/`si_ptr`.

## Full description

According to [`signal(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

> 2. If  the  signal  is  sent  using `sigqueue(2)`, an accompanying value
>    (either an integer or a pointer) can be sent with the  signal.

Does this rule applies when sending signal from kernel? Because I've found a lot of kernel module examples are using `SI_QUEUE`.

Here are some of them

- [Sending signal from kernel to user space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10706540/4123703)
- [Sending realtime signal from a kernel module to user space fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041199/sending-realtime-signal-from-a-kernel-module-to-user-space-fails)
- [How to send signal from kernel to user space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646466/how-to-send-signal-from-kernel-to-user-space)
- [triggering user space with kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360298/triggering-user-space-with-kernel)

In [How to send signal from kernel to user space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646466/how-to-send-signal-from-kernel-to-user-space), there is an interesting *tricky* comment.

> // This is bit of a trickery: SI_QUEUE is normally used by sigqueue from user space, and kernel space should use SI_KERNEL. But if SI_KERNEL is used the real_time data  is not delivered to the user space signal handler function.

This comment specifically states if setting `struct siginfo.si_code` must be set to `SI_QUEUE` instead of `SI_KERNEL`.

However I tested on Ubuntu 18.04 ( kernel 5.4.0-53 ). Either using `SI_QUEUE` or `SI_KERNEL` could get `si_code` from kernel.

### Dig into kernel code

Tried to track down into kernel src to [`__send_signal()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.78/source/kernel/signal.c#L1044).

At L1044 it swtch by the parameter info with a macro

```c
/* These can be the second arg to send_sig_info/send_group_sig_info.  */
#define SEND_SIG_NOINFO ((struct siginfo *) 0)
#define SEND_SIG_PRIV   ((struct siginfo *) 1)
#define SEND_SIG_FORCED ((struct siginfo *) 2)
```

I'm not sure how does macros above transform 0, 1 ,2 but I assume it goes into default case below which is copying the full `struct siginfo info` in my use case.

```c
switch ((unsigned long) info) {  // where info is the struct siginfo parameter
case (unsigned long) SEND_SIG_NOINFO:
    q->info.si_signo = sig;
    q->info.si_errno = 0;
    q->info.si_code = SI_USER;
    q->info.si_pid = task_tgid_nr_ns(current,
                    task_active_pid_ns(t));
    q->info.si_uid = from_kuid_munged(current_user_ns(), current_uid());
    break;
case (unsigned long) SEND_SIG_PRIV:
    q->info.si_signo = sig;
    q->info.si_errno = 0;
    q->info.si_code = SI_KERNEL;
    q->info.si_pid = 0;
    q->info.si_uid = 0;
    break;
default:
    copy_siginfo(&q->info, info);
    if (from_ancestor_ns)
        q->info.si_pid = 0;
    break;
}
```

I may missed something but I'd like to know if there are any documentation or code stating about real-time signal's behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by "calls between userspace"?  kill(), pthread_kill(), sigqueue(), and pthread_sigqueue() all end up doing a syscall; and all signals are delivered by the kernel.

Comment: @Glärbo I meant using system call in user space, contrast to sending directly from kernel module by send_sig_info(). I'll edit the question.

Comment: Tracking the `do_send_sig_info()` call chain through, there are no particular checks for realtime signals, indicating `si_code` does not matter.  However, userspace won't know that a `SI_KERNEL` signal provides a value; it only expects that for `SI_QUEUE` signals.  So, I'd claim `SI_QUEUE` is the only one that makes sense.

Comment: @Glärbo Could you provide userspace code? I may look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but an extended comment, since experimenting will sometimes yield insights.  Technically, this is just an opinion, but with a detailed basis on that opinion.  So, "comment" fits it best.

Here is a simple program that catches SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2, and all POSIX realtime signals (SIGRTMIN+0 to SIGRTMAX-0, inclusive); catcher.c:

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static const char *signal_name(const int signum)
{
    static char name_buffer[16];

    switch (signum) {
    case SIGINT:  return "SIGINT";
    case SIGHUP:  return "SIGHUP";
    case SIGTERM: return "SIGTERM";
    case SIGUSR1: return "SIGUSR1";
    case SIGUSR2: return "SIGUSR2";
    }

    if (signum >= SIGRTMIN && signum <= SIGRTMAX) {
        snprintf(name_buffer, sizeof name_buffer, "SIGRTMIN+%d", signum-SIGRTMIN);
        return (const char *)name_buffer;
    }

    snprintf(name_buffer, sizeof name_buffer, "[%d]", signum);
    return (const char *)name_buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
    const int pid = (int)getpid();
    siginfo_t info;
    sigset_t  mask;
    int       i;

    sigemptyset(&mask);

    /* INT, HUP, and TERM for termination. */
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGHUP);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGTERM);

    /* USR1 and USR2 signals, for comparison to realtime signals. */
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR2);

    /* Realtime signals. */
    for (i = SIGRTMIN; i <= SIGRTMAX; i++)
        sigaddset(&mask, i);

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot block signals: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Process %d is waiting for realtime signals (%d to %d, inclusive).\n", pid, SIGRTMIN, SIGRTMAX);
    printf("        (sigwaitinfo() is at %p, and is called from %p.)\n", (void *)sigwaitinfo, (void *)&&callsite);
    fflush(stdout);

    while (1) {
        /* Clear the signal info structure, so that we can detect nonzero data reliably. */
        memset(&info, 0, sizeof info);

callsite:
        i = sigwaitinfo(&mask, &info);
        if (i == SIGINT || i == SIGTERM || i == SIGHUP) {
           fprintf(stderr, "%d: Received %s. Exiting.\n", pid, signal_name(i));
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        } else
        if (i == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d: sigwaitinfo() failed: %s.\n", pid, strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        printf("%d: Received %s:\n", pid, signal_name(i));

        printf("    si_signo:    %d\n", info.si_signo);
        printf("    si_errno:    %d\n", info.si_errno);
        printf("    si_code:     %d\n", info.si_code);
        printf("    si_pid:      %d\n", (int)info.si_pid);
        printf("    si_uid:      %d\n", (int)info.si_uid);
        printf("    si_status:   %d\n", info.si_status);
        printf("    si_utime:    %.3f\n", (double)info.si_utime / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        printf("    si_stime:    %.3f\n", (double)info.si_stime / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        printf("    si_value.sival_int: %d\n", info.si_value.sival_int);
        printf("    si_value.sival_ptr: %p\n", info.si_value.sival_ptr);
        printf("    si_int:      %d\n", info.si_int);
        printf("    si_ptr:      %p\n", info.si_ptr);
        printf("    si_overrun:  %d\n", info.si_overrun);
        printf("    si_timerid:  %d\n", info.si_timerid);
        printf("    si_addr:     %p\n", info.si_addr);
        printf("    si_band:     %ld (0x%lx)\n", info.si_band, (unsigned long)(info.si_band));
        printf("    si_fd:       %d\n", info.si_fd);
        printf("    si_addr_lsb: %d\n", (int)info.si_addr_lsb);
        printf("    si_lower:    %p\n", info.si_lower);
        printf("    si_upper:    %p\n", info.si_upper);
    }
}
```

Compile it using e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 catcher.c -o catcher`, and run it in a terminal window (`./catcher`).  (It takes no command-line parameters.)

It tells you its process ID, and runs until you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or send it an INT, HUP, or TERM signal.

For the sake of the example, I'll assume it is running as process `12345` later on.

To queue signals to another userspace process, we need a second program, queue.c:

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

static inline int at_end(const char *s)
{
    if (!s)
        return 0; /* NULL pointer is not at end of string. */

    /* Skip whitespace. */
    while (isspace((unsigned char)(*s)))
        s++;

    /* Return true/1 if at end of string, false/0 otherwise. */
    return *s == '\0';
}

static int parse_pid(const char *src, pid_t *to)
{
    long        s;
    const char *end;

    if (!src || at_end(src))
        return -1;

    errno = 0;
    end = src;
    s = strtol(src, (char **)&end, 0);
    if (!errno && at_end(end) && s) {
        const pid_t p = s;
        if ((long)p == s) {
            if (to)
                *to = p;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

static int parse_signum(const char *src, int *to)
{
    const unsigned int  rtmax = SIGRTMAX - SIGRTMIN;
    int                 signum = 0;
    unsigned int        u;
    char                dummy;

    if (!src || !*src)
        return -1;

    /* Skip leading whitespace. */
    while (isspace((unsigned char)(*src)))
        src++;

    /* Skip optional SIG prefix. */
    if (src[0] == 'S' && src[1] == 'I' && src[2] == 'G')
        src += 3;

    do {
        if (!strcmp(src, "USR1")) {
            signum = SIGUSR1;
            break;
        }
        if (!strcmp(src, "USR2")) {
            signum = SIGUSR2;
            break;
        }
        if (!strcmp(src, "RTMIN")) {
            signum = SIGRTMIN;
            break;
        }
        if (!strcmp(src, "RTMAX")) {
            signum = SIGRTMAX;
            break;
        }
        if (sscanf(src, "RTMIN+%u %c", &u, &dummy) == 1 && u <= rtmax) {
            signum = SIGRTMIN + u;
            break;
        }
        if (sscanf(src, "RTMAX-%u %c", &u, &dummy) == 1 && u <= rtmax) {
            signum = SIGRTMAX - u;
            break;
        }
        if (sscanf(src, "%u %c", &u, &dummy) == 1 && u > 0 && (int)u <= SIGRTMAX) {
            signum = u;
            break;
        }

        return -1;
    } while (0);
    if (to)
        *to = signum;
    return 0;
}

static int parse_sigval(const char *src, union sigval *to)
{
    unsigned long u;    /* In Linux, sizeof (unsigned long) == sizeof (void *). */
    long          s;
    int           op = 0;
    const char   *end;

    /* Skip leading whitespace. */
    if (src)
        while (isspace((unsigned char)(*src)))
            src++;

    /* Nothing to parse? */
    if (!src || !*src)
        return -1;

    /* ! or ~ unary operator? */
    if (*src == '!' || *src == '~')
        op = *(src++);

    /* Try parsing as an unsigned long first. */
    errno = 0;
    end = src;
    u = strtoul(src, (char **)&end, 0);
    if (!errno && at_end(end)) {
        if (op == '!')
            u = !u;
        else
        if (op == '~')
            u = ~u;
        if (to)
            to->sival_ptr = (void *)u;
        return 0;
    }

    /* Try parsing as a signed long. */
    errno = 0;
    end = src;
    s = strtol(src, (char **)&end, 0);
    if (!errno && at_end(end)) {
        if (op == '!')
            s = !s;
        else
        if (op == '~')
            s = ~s;
        if (to)
            to->sival_ptr = (void *)s;
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int     pid = (int)getpid();
    pid_t         target = 0;
    int           signum = -1;
    union sigval  value;

    if (argc != 4 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        const char *argv0 = (argc > 0 && argv && argv[0] && argv[0][0]) ? argv[0] : "(this)";
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv0);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s PID SIGNAL VALUE\n", argv0);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Queues signal SIGNAL to process PID, with value VALUE.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "You can use negative PIDs for process group -PID.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return (argc <= 2) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (parse_pid(argv[1], &target) || !target) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid process ID.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (parse_signum(argv[2], &signum)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid signal name or number.\n", argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (parse_sigval(argv[3], &value)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid value.\n", argv[3]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

callsite:
    if (sigqueue(target, signum, value) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Process %d failed to send signal %d with value %p to process %d: %s.\n", pid, signum, value.sival_ptr, (int)target, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else {
        printf("Process %d sent signal %d with value %p to process %d.\n", pid, signum, value.sival_ptr, (int)target);
        printf("        (sigqueue() is at %p, calling sigqueue() at %p.)\n", (void *)sigqueue, (void *)(&&callsite));
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Compile it too using e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 queue.c -o queue`.  It takes three command-line parameters; run it without parameters (or with just -h or --help) to see its usage.

If the catcher is running as process 12345, we can run e.g. `./queue 12345 SIGRTMIN+5 0xcafedeadbeefbabe` to queue a signal to the catcher, and see the output.

If the queue process happens to be 54321, we can expect the following output on x86-64 architecture:

```
    si_signo:    39
    si_errno:    0
    si_code:     -1
    si_pid:      54321
    si_uid:      1001
    si_status:   -1091585346
    si_utime:    0.000
    si_stime:    0.000
    si_value.sival_int: -1091585346
    si_value.sival_ptr: 0xcafedeadbeefbabe
    si_int:      -1091585346
    si_ptr:      0xcafedeadbeefbabe
    si_overrun:  1001
    si_timerid:  54321
    si_addr:     0x3e90000d431
    si_band:     4299262317617 (0x3e90000d431)
    si_fd:       -1091585346
    si_addr_lsb: -17730
    si_lower:    (nil)
    si_upper:    (nil)
```

(Other hardware architectures may vary slightly due to byte order and long/pointer size differences.)

Of these fields, only `si_signo == SIGRTMIN+5`, `si_errno == 0`, and `si_code == -1 == SI_QUEUE` are defined for all signals.

The rest of the fields are actually in various unions, which means that the subset of fields we can access, depends on the `si_code` field (as per [man 2 sigaction](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)).

When `si_code == SI_QUEUE`, we have `si_pid` (the pid of the process that did sigqueue(), or 0 if it is from the kernel), `si_int == si_value.sival_int`, and `si_ptr == si_value.sival_ptr`. The rest of the fields are essentially in an union of these those, so by accessing them, we're just type-punning the contents, getting garbage.

When `si_code == SI_KERNEL`, the userspace does not know which of the unions was populated.  That is, we don't know if the `si_pid` and `si_int` or `si_ptr` are valid, or whether the kernel intended us to examine `si_addr` (similar to SIGBUS) or some other fields.

This means that for the userspace to understand correctly a signal sent by the kernel that contains pertinent data in `si_int` or `si_ptr`, the logical and least-surprise option is to have `si_code == SI_QUEUE` and `si_pid == 0`.

(Indeed, I do recall seeing this in real life, but cannot remember for the life of me where.  If I did, I could have made this an answer, but because I don't, this has to stay as an extended comment; report of observed behaviour only.)

Finally, if we look at the userspace API for Linux kernel 5.9.9, we can see the definition of `siginfo_t` in [include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9.9/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h#L32).  Remember, this is not how C libraries expose the information; this is how the Linux kernel delivers the information to userspace. Combining the definitions for readability, and ignoring certain arch differences (like member order), we have essentially

```c
typedef struct siginfo {
    union {
        struct {
           int si_signo;
           int si_errno;
           int si_code;

           union {

                struct {
                    __kernel_pid_t    _pid;
                    __kernel_uid32_t  _uid;
                } _kill;

                struct {
                    __kernel_timer_t  _tid;
                    int               _overrun;
                    sigval_t          _sigval;
                    int               _sys_private;  /* not to be passed to user */
                } _timer;

                struct {
                    __kernel_pid_t    _pid;
                    __kernel_uid32_t  _uid;
                    sigval_t          _sigval;
                } _rt;

                struct {
                    __kernel_pid_t    _pid;
                    __kernel_uid32_t  _uid;
                    int               _status;
                    __ARCH_SI_CLOCK_T _utime;
                    __ARCH_SI_CLOCK_T _stime;
                } _sigchld;

                struct {
                    void __user      *_addr;
                    int               _trapno;
                    union {
                        short           _addr_lsb;
                        struct {
                            char            _dummy_bnd[__ADDR_BND_PKEY_PAD];
                            void __user    *_lower;
                            void __user    *_upper;
                        } _addr_bnd;
                        struct {
                            char            _dummy_pkey[__ADDR_BND_PKEY_PAD];
                            __u32           _pkey;
                        } _addr_pkey;
                    };
                } _sigfault;

                struct {
                    __ARCH_SI_BAND_T  _band;
                    int               _fd;
                } _sigpoll;

                struct {
                    void __user      *_call_addr;
                    int               _syscall;
                    unsigned int      _arch;
                } _sigsys;


           } _sifields;
        };

        int _si_pad[SI_MAX_SIZE/sizeof(int)];
    };
} siginfo_t;
```

So, essentially, the kernel can provide the fields in only one of the `_rt`, `_kill`, `_timer`, `_sigchld`, `_sigfault`, `_sigpoll`, or `_sigsys` structures -- because they alias each other -- and the only fields for the userspace to determine which one to access, are the common ones: `si_signo`, `si_errno`, and `si_code`.  (Although `si_errno` really is reserved for errno code.)

Existing userspace code – using the guidance of `man 2 sigaction` – knows to examine `si_ptr`/`si_int` only when `si_code == SI_QUEUE`.  So, it is logical for the kernel to emit such signals with `si_pid == 0` and `si_code == SI_QUEUE`.

The final wrinkle is the C library.  For example, the GNU C library uses one or two POSIX realtime signals internally (typically 32 and 33; among other things, to synchronize things like process uid, which are actually per-thread properties in Linux, but per-process properties in POSIX).  So, a C library may "consume" odd-looking signals, because it might see them as its own.  (Usually not, though, as the signal number is pretty decisive!)

More importantly, the siginfo_t structure used by a particular C library may not be anything like the one used by the Linux kernel (the library just copies the fields as needed from a temporary copy of the structure).  So, if one relies on details on how the Linux kernel provides the siginfo_t, instead of how siginfo_t is used in practice, one can be bitten by such translation layer in the C library.

Here, again, the least surprising case for a signal with a `si_int`/`si_ptr` payload, from the kernel, would be `si_pid == 0` and `si_code == SI_QUEUE`.  There is no sane reason for a C library to consume or drop such signals.  And, the only difference between such and normal userspace queued signals is then `si_pid` being zero (which is not a valid process ID).

At this point, we could claim the answer to the stated question is *"well, no, not really; but you want to use SI_QUEUE so the C library and/or the userspace process does not get confused"*.  However, that is not an authoritative answer, just an opinion.

Comment: Please correct me if I understood incorrectly. In short, you mean a programmer _may_ write a check to examine `si_int`/`si_ptr` in signal action handler only when `si_code == SI_QUEUE`. Since `si_pid == 0` is descriptive enough to tell that it's coming from kernel, using SI_QUEUE would make sense?

Comment: Your explanation make sense. Since kernel code serves for userspace, the data carried by siginfo should serve userspace program. Where `si_code == SI_QUEUE` should be the sign of checking `siginfo`'s `si_int`/`si_ptr`.

Comment: @LouisGo: The latter comment, precisely.  (The former comment only applies if the underlying C library does it, i.e. uses a very different structure for siginfo_t than the Linux kernel does, and only copies si_int/si_ptr when si_code==SI_QUEUE.  I do not think any C library does so, but it is technically plausible, in my opinion.)